# Selenium - xpath definition

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying the following xpath to check box "In Process"

I am using the following code but getting a *No such Element Exception*:

[image]
[image]

```
String ds = "//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_Content_MainPlaceHolder_cblStatuses_1']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(ds)).click();
```

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots of code. Just post the related html source code with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try belo code:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(ctl00_ctl00_Content_MainPlaceHolder_cblStatuses_1)));
    element.click();
```

Note:

- If its not working then check your element is dynami **or**
- If its present within iframe

Comment: The element is not dynamic. But, seems like its present within a frame within frame.
But when I try iframe size, it gives me only one. It is not able to find the iframe as well when to switch to that frame.

Comment: can you please prvide url ?

Comment: Unfortunately this works only within our Company. 
int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
  driver.switchTo().frame("frameContent");
These are the two commands I tried

Comment: so if you handle your switching will resolve your issue. you can switch to iframe using name, id ,index and you can switch to main page using switchTo().defaultContent().

Comment: <iframe id="frameContent" name="ContentFrame" src="about:blank" class="heightWidth100" style="border: 0; display:block;"></iframe> is the html for the iframe
I tried using driver.switchTo().frame("frameContent") . Getting the error org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id frameContent

Comment: Can you ppost entire DOM I think multiple iframes are present on the page or check your desired element present within same iframe

Comment: Yes, thats correct. There were frames within frames.Figured out the solution. I had to switch to outer frame. Then I had to switch to the inner frame. Then I was able to interact with the Webelement I wanted. Thank you. This is the first time I dealt with iframe

Answer (score 0):

To complete and add extra layers of security, you can use the following XPath :

```
//table[@empowertype="CheckBoxList"][preceding::label[1][.="Statuses"]]//input[@type="checkbox" and @value="In Process"]
```

Output : 1 `input` element

Comment: Actually like SeleniumUser002 mentioned there are iframes within iframes. So had to switch to each one of them to access the element